# Is row locking needed to increment value in a transaction

Tags: mysql

Will the following code work as intended (the counter_field increases by 1 every time)?

```
START TRANSACTION;
(other queries here)
UPDATE mytable SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
(other queries here)
COMMIT;
```

Do I need to use row locking? Should I use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`?

Not sure if it matters but I am using InnoDB with REPEATABLE READ (default) isolation level.

Comment: The update you've written is already atomic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is automatic row locking (SELECT ... FOR UPDATE) when performing any UPDATE query.

Comment: The implication that a prior SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is executed is false. You need to clarify this.